# NSStream and Sockets, NSStreamDelegate methods not being called

Tags: objective-c, nsstream

I've followed the guide [Setting Up Socket Streams](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/NetworkStreams.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002277-1002597) and have effectively duplicated that code in my class. No matter what I try the delegate methods just don't seem to get called.

In the header file I have (basically):

```
@interface myClass : NSObject <NSStreamDelegate> {
    NSInputStream *inputStream;
    NSOutputStream *outputStream;
}
- (void)connect;
@end;
```

The connect method:

```
- (void)connect {
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;

    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)@"host.example.com", 1234, &readStream, &writeStream);

    inputStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
    outputStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
    [inputStream setDelegate:self];
    [outputStream setDelegate:self];
    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [inputStream open];
    [outputStream open];
}
```

Also tried using `CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToCFHost()` and `[NSStream getStreamsToHost:port:inputStream:outputStream:` - all with exactly the same result.

I've set a breakpoint at the beginning of the `connect` method, stepped through every line and every pointer is valid and seems to point to the correct object.

In GDB, after the `setDelegate` calls, `po [inputStream delegate]` prints `<myClass: 0x136380>` as expected, so it has set the delegate correctly.

For the life of me I can't work out why it refuses to call the `stream:handleEvent:` method on my class:

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode {
    NSLog(@"got an event");
}
```

Hopefully I've missed something really simple and obvious and a second pair of eyes can spot my mistake.

Thanks in advance to anyone who has the patience and taken the time to read this far!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In the lines like this:

```
[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Instead of using `[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]` I changed it to `[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]`.

#### EDIT 2011-05-30:

The reason this did not work is because I was setting up the sockets in a background thread via `+[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:]`.

Doing it that way created a new run loop, which after reading the [run loop developer documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW1) I discovered that you need to tell the NSRunLoop to run manually.

Running it in the same run loop as the main thread was fine on performance, though I was able to squeeze a bit more performance out by writing a wrapper class and running all network I/O on a background thread.

Comment: @user102008 Edited my response to explain.

Comment: could u potentially post the ending code? For some reason, I changed the [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]  to [NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] and the connection doesn't fails shortly after it initiates

Comment: you nailed it!  after removing my socket client from the main thread, i stopped listening to the inputStream (even though my outputStream was still working, as i could monitor on the socket server).  i just changed the inputstream`s run loop   and bingo!  UPVOTED :)

Comment: both your question and answer helped me to know where to go, but im not sure how to start and connect using a simple button??

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had the same problem using Monotouch and opening the socket in a Task. Using Main loop instead of current (Task's thread) solved the problem.

Comment: one year later, this answer helped me again.. funny reading comments and discovering you commented on this answer before!

Answer (score 9):

That solution will work if & only if you don't have blocking work on thread 0. This is often OK, but a better solution is to create a new thread (i.e. using a class method to create the thread on demand) and then enqueue on that thread.
i.e.

```
+ (NSThread *)networkThread {
    static NSThread *networkThread = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;

    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        networkThread =
             [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                     selector:@selector(networkThreadMain:)
                                       object:nil];
        [networkThread start];
    });

    return networkThread;
}

+ (void)networkThreadMain:(id)unused {
    do {
        @autoreleasepool {
            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
        }
    } while (YES);
}

- (void)scheduleInCurrentThread
{
    [inputstream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
                           forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}
```

With this, you can schedule the input stream using:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(scheduleInCurrentThread)
             onThread:[[self class] networkThread]
           withObject:nil
        waitUntilDone:YES];
```

This will allow you to run your network operations without worrying about deadlocks anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have another related problem. When stream is being written onto, user may go ahead and move the application in background. I would prefer to keep the stream running even in background. I tried using beginBackgroundTask... to achieve that but no matter what I do, I cant make my picture uploading work when app is in background. Do you this this will be at all possible?

Comment: One of our tutorial apps does this. If you're still looking for help, you might want to check it out at https://parse.com/tutorials/anypic#post Check out the bit about 'saving the PFObject.' Though our framework hides it, the bit inside the background task makes a network call.

Comment: Does this code adequately drain the autorelease pool regularly? The documentation for `-[NSRunLoop run]` says that it will repeatedly invoke `runMode:beforeDate:`. That means there is no chance for the autorelease pool to be drained in between those invocations.